# DDD: Where to Place Interfaces (ports)

Tags: domain-driven-design

I know that IRepository has to put in domain folder, but for the rest of the interfaces such as: IQueryBus, ICommandBus... should I put them in Application folder?

I've seen a lot examples where some of them put this kind of interfaces in domain like /domain/bus/IQueryBus, /domain/bus/ICommandBus and other put them in /application/bus/IQueryBus /application/bus/ICommandBus. I'm not sure what is the best option and why. Also I've read this article https://herbertograca.com/2017/11/16/explicit-architecture-01-ddd-hexagonal-onion-clean-cqrs-how-i-put-it-all-together/ that explain: It’s important to note that the Ports (Interfaces) belong inside the business logic, while the adapters belong outside. so, if I understood very well all interfaces have to put in domain folder?

Answer (score 4):

First of all , we have to distinguish the aspect of the port:

Driver ports (primary ports). They are interfaces offering the use cases of our application. So they belong to the application layer. They are called by the driver adapters and they are implemented by the application layer.

Driven ports (secondary ports). Here it depends. A driven port is an abstraction (interface) for doing some task that is performed by an external actor outside your application. If such task is logic that is independent of whatever domain, then the port interface belongs to the application layer (for example a port for authentication and authorization). If the tasks are logic of the domain of your application, then the port belongs to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I will refer to the word *context* as a space that can be a package or a folder or whatever container you can use to separate concepts.
You should put each interface in the context determined by its purpose.
Generic interfaces like `ICommandBus` can be put inside an "infrastructure" context, the interfaces offering domain behavior inside the domain context, if inside it you have a more specific context inside the domain context use that one.
That kind of interfaces are like bridges between contexts, so, each context has its own interfaces offering functionalities implemented in a different context.